# Writing hierarchy from derived column to JSON sink without column name Azure Dataflow

Tags: json, azure, transformation, azure-data-factory

I am creating a derived column to create JSON structure in Azure Dataflow to write it into a JSON sink.
I called the hierarchy complex column "orders" so when the derived column is written to JSON sink every JSON object is an "orders" object.

[enter image description here][1]

How could I remove the "orders" container so the final JSON structure is only a set of JSON obects without the "orders" structure.

This is the final JSON sink after being written in Azure DataFlow:

```
{
    "orders": {
        "customer": {
            "ordering": {
                "customer_account": "4226010"
            }
        },
        "order_id": "802202100000100100A"
    }
}
```

I would like it like this :

```
    {
    "customer": {
        "ordering": {
            "customer_account": "4226010"
        }
    },
    "order_id": "802202100000100100A"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Derived Column transformation, define the structure as you have in the 2nd example above. Create a new column called "customer" and in the Expression box in Expression Builder, click on the curly braces for the current customer structure in Expression Values.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually the only thing I needed to do was to remove the top container of the structure ("orders") and create the substructures at the same level as other columns.

Comment: Use the technique that I described here. Make a new structure called "customer" because it is inside the "orders" structure.